# SSRS 2012 - 1 parameter for 3 columns

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a challenge with SSRS 2012. I have 1 parameter in which I need to be able to select multiple values from 3 different columns. I was only able to make this work with selecting 1 value, then it would look at all columns and return the value. However, I am not sure how I can accomplish this with multiple values.

This is the expression that makes it work with 1 parameter and 1 value for 3 columns. I tried using `IN` instead of =, but to no avail.

```
WHERE (Customer_Category1 = @prmCategory OR Customer_Category2 = @prmCategory OR Customer_Category3 = @prmCategory)
```

[image]

I have researched for hours without finding any information.

Please help if you can. I'm open for any suggestions or recommendations. I am still pretty new at the parameter realm.

Comment: Can you give an example of your data and your parameter values? I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: For sure. Above is a snapshot of my one parameter I have, and I am trying to select multiple values from this drop down parameter which then needs to look at the 3 columns, and if any matches, then return the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `in` should be the solution here. However, it is possible that your syntax was not correct. Try this:

```
WHERE (Customer_Category1 in (@prmCategory) OR Customer_Category2 in (@prmCategory) OR Customer_Category3 in (@prmCategory))
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. The funny thing is, I tried a similar approach on the first turn around. However, I did not wrap any of columns or parameters in ().  Thanks a ton for your help!! Happy Holidays!